# Default Folder change For Attach File in outlook 2013

Tags: outlook-2013

My default folder to add / insert attachement (Attch File) **Documents** but i want to change it to **Desktop**

So whenever i want to add / insert attacment (Attch File) in reply / new email it should go to **Desktop** by default insted **Document**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found wrok arround And it works.

Open Word then go to File >> Options >> Save >> Save Douments >> Default local file location >> Browse and select location.

thats it. close Word the reopen Outlook and check if the same is works or not.